# c# custom datatable view

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

Can following thing be done?

[image]

The red rectangled datatable should be modified as the other row.

I am using c#, DataTable with MS-SQL.
I want to give shown type of view of second row to the user in a windows.

I'll be having at least 500-600 rows like this out of 1000 rows. Which can be shorten down to 1000-600/3 = 800.
(Perhabs, I can take this chance because the operation will not be time consuming.)
The user will be having ease in putting data only once in place of puttinig it thrice .. will save time for them and over all performance.

Please ask question for help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want us to ask you questions? Strange!

Comment: @Nayan: So that I can get any pointer, from where should I start. :D Usually whenever I ask question anywhere, I get several questions regarding the issue. And from those only I get the answer by my self. getting everyones 1 minute view helps a lot. That's y I asked to ask it.

Comment: Well, rule of the thumb: you get asked question because you did not post required info. But here, you *know* that you are not providing good enough info to even start with. That's why - WEIRD! =)

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about this here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/, "Concatenating row values in Transact-SQL".

The conclusion is that this is not a trivial task and can be achieved using SQL or in code.

I would probably perform the database querying in code and then modify the DataTable and databind the grid with the modified DataTable. If the grid allows editing, then you have to perform the reverse transform before saving it to the database.

Comment: Hey, I've been bg with other works alike .. thanks I'll try it from 15'Oct. I see this is relevant one.